# What's wrong in this Module snippet?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I want to have private properties in an object. The following code doens't work:

```
var GameModule = (function(ns){

    function Game(ctx) {
        var self   = this, //use self in callback methods (requestAnimationFrame etc)
            ctx    = ctx,

        var dx = 1,
            dy = 1;

        console.log(dx, dy); //writes 1,1,

        console.log(self.dx, self.dy); //writes undefined, undefined
    }

    ns.Game = Game;
    return ns;

})(GameModule || {});

//somewhere later in a different file
$(document).ready(function(){
   var game = new GameModule.Game(some_ctx);
});
```

It seems like the `vars` are analogous to static members, not private.

Do I have to write `this.dx = 1` to make the variable accessible (in member functions for instance)? Doesn't it make the variable public?

Answer (score 1):

To define class properties in Javascript, you do it like so ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xPCW/)):

```
var Class = function(){

    this.property = 'now this is a property';

    Class.staticProperty = 'and this is a static property';

    var property = 'this is NOT a property, but a local variable';
};

Class.prototype.propertyToo = 'this is also a property';

var object = new Class();

console.log(object.property);
console.log(object.propertyToo);
console.log(Class.staticProperty);
```

JavaScript by the language itself did not provide any access modifier, so private properties can not be done without [tricky methods](http://blog.ramonlechuga.com/2010/08/12/private-public-properties-for-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

There were several errors in the module you had created. Firstly, `dx` is a private variable when defined with `var dx`. It can be accessed inside of the function, but not outside unless exposed through a return statement which would make it psuedo public.

However, there is a key distinction that I believe you missed. There are two types of functions. A function which can be called such as `function func(){}` and a **Function Object** which is when the `new` keyword is issued to a function, making it into a Function Object, such as `new func();`, or in your example here `new GameModule.Game(some_ctx);`.

Once `Game` has been instanced with the `new` keyword, `Game` is a `Function Object`, and is an `instanceof Game`. At this point, variables or functions may be attached the the function object using the `this` keyword. Inside of a `Function Object`, `this` refers to the object, whereas outside of a `Function Object` `this` refers to the window. You cannot use `var this.variableName` because that is not valid syntax. You are not creating a variable, you are extending the object. Thus, `var dx` and `this.dx` are two different locations in memory and have different values.

I hope that clarifies some of this for you.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCZKG/

js:

```
var GameModule = (function(ns){

    function Game(ctx) {
        var self = this,
        ctx = ctx,
        dx = 1,
        dy = 1;
        self.dx = 2,
        self.dy = 2;

        console.log(dx, dy);//1 1
        console.log(self.dx, self.dy);//2 2
    }

    ns.Game = Game;
    return ns;
})(GameModule || {});

var some_ctx = {};
var game = new GameModule.Game(some_ctx);
```

Comment: so `var dx` is a variable inside a function, but `this.dx` is an object's property, right? On the other hand, if I don't write `var` but just `dx` then if `window` has a `dx` property then that will be used which is the same as writing `this.dx` (in some occasions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but one issue I see is that your not executing Game by:

```
ns.Game = Game();
```

But to make a var accessible outside of the object, you have to either do this.dx or have a return statement like:

```
return {
  dx: dx,
  dy: dy
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?